# Scroll to predefined option when clicked on select element does not work

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome, browser

When I click on the select to choose an option I want the select box to automatically scroll down to show a predefined option.
This code works in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome. It works in Chrome only for a multiple select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectId").click(function() {
    $("#selectId").find("option[value='24']")[0].scrollIntoView();
  });
});
```

```html
<select title="Title" data-header="select" id="selectId">
  <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
  <option value="1">1 </option>
  <option value="2">2 </option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't believe what you're attempting to do will work in any modern browser. If you need this behaviour you'll need to use a library which converts the original `select` element in to HTML which can allows for much greater UI control, such as Select2

Comment: I can't even get IE to let me see SO. It opens Edge and tells me it's better there lol

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sums it up for me, you are mixing operating system UI (the select options aren't part of the webpage, they can even appear outside of the window) with HTML elements. I am *very* surprised if it works as you say it does in IE. A silly option that you may not have thought of, if you just make the option you want selected it will autoscroll to it `<option value="24" selected="selected">24</option>`.

Comment: @Djave I dont want the option 24 to be selected when the element loads, I want the "Choose one" title to be displayed in the select box then when the select box is clicked select and scroll automatically to the option 24. What do you mean with the select options are not part of the webpage? They are manipulable as DOM HTMLOptionElement objects

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how would be achieved the desired behaviour with select2?

Comment: `<option value="31">31</option>` is a `DOM HTMLOptionElement`. This: https://imgur.com/a/MOBxJ2P is clearly outside of the webpage, and is managed mostly by the Operating System. So you can select an option, but you can't tell it to `scrollIntoView()` because it isn't a DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved this behaviour using [JQuery Select2](https://select2.org/) this way:

```
$("#selectId").select2().on('select2:open', function() {
    $("#selectId").val("7").trigger('change');
    $("#selectId").off("select2:open");
});
```